# adding study numbers by scanning a text string in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I was wondering how could I add study numbers instead of the study names. Here is an example:

My original data frame has a column for SOURCE that looks like this:

```
df <- 
SOURCE
studyA
studyB
studyC
studyA
```

How can I give unique numbers for the study SOURCE? The result should be like this:

```
df <- 
SOURCE   STUDY
studyA   1
studyB   2
studyC   3
studyA   1
```

Basically something that scans the `SOURCE` column and gives numbers if it find a new study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the 'SOURCE' column to `factor` class specifying the `levels` as the `unique` elements of 'SOURCE`and coerce to`numeric` class.

```
df$STUDY <- as.numeric(factor(df$SOURCE, levels= unique(df$SOURCE)))
```

Or we `match` the 'SOURCE' to the `unique` elements of `SOURCE` to get the numeric index.

```
df$STUDY <- with(df, match(SOURCE, unique(SOURCE)))
df
#  SOURCE STUDY
#1 studyA     1
#2 studyB     2
#3 studyC     3
#4 studyA     1
```

Comment: Thank you! Life is easy!